# Передача данных с debian на ВМ windows через туннель

Tags: linux, windows, виртуальная-машина

Здравствуйте.
На моей рабочей машине установлен debian. Далее я соединяюсь с сервером, где создаю туннель до ВМ на Windows. Далее я могу просматривать рабочий стол на Windows через "просмотр удалённых рабочих столов". 
Существует ли возможность перекидывать данные таким образом?

Дополнено: Прокладываю туннель до ВМ следующим образом: ssh -L 1111:VM_IP:3389 user_name@server

Comment: термин «туннель» — это настолько широчайшее понятие, что без конкретики на ваш вопрос ответить весьма затруднительно. дополните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос конкретикой, нажав [edit]

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Дополнил описание

Comment: раз вы можете подключиться к серверу программой ssh, можно воспользоваться для копирования файлов/каталог на/с сервера программой scp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставил программу Remmina. Можно соединяться с ВМ посредством туннеля + создавать общую папку.